# Get full JID from xmpp server or client for IQ Request

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, openfire, xmppframework

I am working on an iOS app that uses the XMPPFramework and openfire xmpp server. I am almost done, but am stuck with getting my iOS to receive IQ request. I was able to receive messages and send IQ request but not receive IQ requests.

I tried sending the IQ request from iOS client and the XMPP server, but the iOS app just ignored the IQ request. After a long time of research, I narrowed down my issue. It turns out that I was sending IQ request to the bare JID. The Bare JID was routed to the server and not directly to the client.

The solution that I found was to get the full JID and set the "to" IQ message to the full JID and not the bare JID. I am having difficulties figuring out how I can get the resource, or make the bare JID to a full JID.

Could someone please give me some suggestions? I want to be able to get the full JID so that I can send IQ request to my iOS client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subscribe to the presence of the person you want to send the IQ to:

```
<presence type='subscribe' from='me@example.com' to='contact@example.com'/>
```

They have to accept your subscription:

```
<presence type='subscribed' to='me@example.com' from='contact@example.com'/>
```

You'll then start getting presence that includes the full JID from all of their clients:

```
<presence to='me@example.com' from='contact@example.com/home'/>
```

If they have a full-featured client, they will send you presence marked up with [XEP-0115](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html), so you can tell if their client supports your IQ protocol before you send it to them:

```
<presence to='me@example.com' from='contact@example.com/home'>
  <c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' 
     hash='sha-1'
     node='http://code.google.com/p/exodus'
     ver='QgayPKawpkPSDYmwT/WM94uAlu0='/>
</presence>
```

Comment: Is there an api that I can call to directly get the full JID of the user from my XMPP openfire or XMPPFramework client? I am writing an app that needs to send an IQ request to a full JID, but I don't know what functions I can call to get the full JID from a username / bare JID. I am still a bit new to this, and I have access to the backend of my server or my iOS app.

Comment: um so the method that you're proposing is that from my backend server, I tell my plugin to send a presence subscription, so that the full JID is returned from the iOS app? Once I get the full JID, I can send the iq request? A little redundant? My plugin has complete backend access and I still need to send a presence subscription request?

Comment: @user1157352 If you're writing the client, and your server component has a fixed address, you could skip a subscription and have the client send directed presence to the component when it logs in - thus revealing its full JID. Presence is the standard way to do what you want in XMPP. The alternative you seem to be suggesting is writing a server-specific plugin to get the full JIDs, but that's a different question as it depends on your server's internal API.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think presence solved my issue. I seem to be able to receive the full JID by using presence. 

I will have my server send a Presence request to my iOS app client, and have the app response it's full JID. Then with the full JID, I will have my server send a set IQ to my app.